# xaringan presentation not displaying html widgets, even when knitting provided template

Tags: html, r, xaringan

The HTML widgets that are supposed to work within xaringan presentations are not showing up / rendering on the slides for me. Even when I knit the provided template. As a reproducible example, when I knit:

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, PBC"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---
```

```
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

```
DT::datatable(
  head(iris, 10),
  fillContainer = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 8)
)
```

All I get for slide 2 is:

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsTy1.png)

I would like to include DT::datatable() tables in my presentations. They knit fine to other RMarkdown documents at the moment, like ioslides_presentation and html_document. Here is my session info

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.17.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        rstudioapi_0.13   knitr_1.30.4      servr_0.21        magrittr_2.0.1   
 [6] R6_2.5.0          rlang_0.4.10      fansi_0.4.2       stringr_1.4.0     tools_4.0.3      
[11] xfun_0.20         xaringan_0.19.1   sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_2.2.0         withr_2.4.0      
[16] htmltools_0.5.1   crosstalk_1.1.1   assertthat_0.2.1  yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.27    
[21] crayon_1.3.4      later_1.1.0.1     htmlwidgets_1.5.3 promises_1.1.1    rsconnect_0.8.16 
[26] glue_1.4.2        evaluate_0.14     mime_0.9          rmarkdown_2.6     stringi_1.5.3    
[31] compiler_4.0.3    jsonlite_1.7.2    httpuv_1.5.5
```

And I just updated RStudio today :
Version 1.4.1103
© 2009-2021 RStudio, PBC
"Wax Begonia" (458706c3, 2021-01-06) for macOS

perhaps also useful:

```
> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.11.2’
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I cannot reproduce; is this perhaps an issue with the RStudio HTML viewer? Does the presentation render correctly when you view it in your browser (click the "Open in browser" button at the top of the RStudio HTML viewer window)?

Comment: No, it is the same exact issue when I open in Firefox or Safari.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the same issue on my windows PC. When using the default template for xaringan both leaflet and DT don't show up as expected and as reported by @vcannataro. When I do the exact same thing on my MacBook Air with the M1 chip however, both leaflet and DT show up as expected. I am running version 0.15 on windows and 0.18 on mac but I don't think it's a version issue since you are on a more recent one. I would make a new issue on the GitHub repository about this and I agree it is weird.

Comment: @Ricky I should've added that I'm on Windows 10, and I can render the slides correctly in Chrome. Using: `xaringan_0.19` and `R_4.0.3`. Do the other (text-only) slides render correctly?

Comment: @MauritsEvers yes, everything thus far has been rendering correctly except leaflet and DT. Furthermore, if I change the beginning from `output: xaringan::moon_reader` to `output: html_document` the html widgets render perfectly within the standard html document output .

Comment: @Ricky To follow up, you are correct about the version issue. I just tried knitting it using xaringan 0.15 and 0.19—same issue for me either way.

Comment: @vcannataro That is very strange. I have no issues on Windows 10 and MacOS. Same versions except for RStudio which is 1.3.1093. I need to open the slide in the browser though (instead of the internal RStudio Viewer) for the slides to render correctly.

Comment: MauritsEvers I know what you are talking about, this especially happens when I embed a webpage or url using knitr where it only renders in the browser, but I can confirm that is not the issue here. When I render the default example on my macbook it shows both leaflet and DT perfectly fine within the RStudio viewer. On windows it does not show up either within RStudio nor within Chrome. I think @vcannataro should make an issue on github so Yihui can see it: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues
If you don't want to for some reason, I'm happy to do it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Ricky. I posted it here: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/293

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A recent update to rmarkdown (in version 2.6) changed how HTML widgets are included in the output file to use pandoc's raw HTML blocks. Unfortunately, this feature isn't compatible with the JavaScript markdown library used by xaringan. You can disable this feature and resolve the issue with htmlwidgets in xaringan slides by setting

```
options(htmltools.preserve.raw = FALSE)
```

Here's the related [NEWS entry from rmarkdown 2.6](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/NEWS.md#rmarkdown-26):

> Specify that htmltools::htmlPreserve() should use the pandoc raw attribute rather than preservation tokens when pandoc >= v2.0. Note that this option will have the intended effect only for versions of htmltools >= 0.5.0.9003.

Comment: Your point saved my time a lot. Thank you!